# Clean Up Prestashop's Original Product Images to Reduce Storage Usage

Tags: command-line-interface, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I manage a Prestashop site built with version 1.6, which has 1000's of products on it.

Each time a new product image is uploaded, Prestashop stores it in a file structure for future access, as well as resizing images down for various requirements of the current theme (category page, product, basket etc).

With the large quantity of products and 14 smaller versions created, they're quickly filling up storage space.

I'm looking to find a way to delete the original image and replace it with a copy of the largest resized image.

e.g. Product 5010 has it's original image named 5010.jpg and the next largest is 5010-big_default_2x.jpg

I want to delete 5010.jpg and copy 5010-big_default_2x.jpg to 5010.jpg, taking it's place

I'm thinking some sort of cli recursive regex search for files which are numeric and end in .jpg, store the filename, delete the file and copy [filename]-big_default_2x.jpg to [filename].jpg

The server runs on Centos 6.7 with full root access.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: What did you try and what's your actual problem?

Comment: I believe the best way to do it will be with a command line script, however I'm not sure how to create one which can achieve this.

My attempts to find the original image file in the first place haven't worked: `find . -regextype sed -regex "./[0-9]+\.jpg"`

Comment: The point of keeping the original image is to be able to regenerate the images or generate an image to a newly added format. I assume you want to replace them because they're very large > 2MB ?

Comment: Yes, the originals being uploaded are just too large, using 4GB of space. The next size down will be sufficient for regenerating any future smaller files - which is why I want a copy of it to take the place of the original image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something as simple as:

```
images.php
==========

require 'config/config.inc.php'

$productIds = Db::getInstance(...) // Select all products IDs

$i = 0;
$s = 0;
foreach ($productIds as $id_product) {
  $bits = explode('', (string)$id_product);
  $directory = _PS_IMG_DIR.'/'.implode('/', $bits);
  $filePath = $directory.'/'.(string)$id_product.'.jpg';

  if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    $resizedFilePath = $directory.'/'.(string)$id_product.'-large_default.jpg';
    $resizedImageData = file_get_contents(resizedFilePath);
    file_put_contents($filePath, $resizedImageData);
    $s++;
  }
  $i++;
}

echo 'Folders: '.$i.'; Successful copies: '.$s;
```

Upload this via FTP and call it in your browser once

Comment: Great, thanks - I just had it in my head to use the command line. I made a few slight tweaks, but it's the core of what you've suggested. Over 1GB now saved, thanks.

Comment: Nice job. Thanks for the help. I was wondering if we delete them it is a good idea or not, as I tried to rename the original image with some thing random and it seems like working with no issues. I think the only place it goes wrong is where some module is looking for the original image